# Removing sentences containing a keyword in java

Tags: java

I am been searching online and on here on how I can remove a line that contains one or two words but I can't find anything on java. This is the code I have right now:

```
try {
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Readfile.txt"));
  String line = reader.readLine();
  while(line !=null)
  {
    for(int i = 0 ; i<newarray.length;i++){
      if(line.contains(newarray[i])){
        System.out.println(line);
      }
    }
    line=reader.readLine();
  }
} catch (Exception ex) {
  System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

It reads sentences from a text file, but before it prints them out, I want to delete some sentences that contains a keyword, e.g. fun.

Comment: aren't you able to delete the line from your txt file ??

Comment: What about adding the scanned line in a `LinkedList<String>` iff `line.contains("fun")` returns `false`?

Comment: @PremGenError My text files contains more than 100 sentences, so I thought doing this would be easier than deleting the sentences one my one.

Comment: Do you really want to handle *sentences* or *lines*?

Comment: @JoachimSauer The sentence's are in a line. E.g each sentence is on one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
//BufferedReader stuff etc.
List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
words.add("fun");
words.add("something");

String line;
while( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
   boolean found = false;
   for(String word: words)
   {
       if(line.contains(word))
       {
           found = true;
           break;
       }
   }

   if(found) continue;
   System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(line.contains(newarray[i])){
    line = line.replace("fun" ,"");
    System.out.println(line);
  }
```

Try this it will delete the word before printing it.

Comment: I tired this, but I'm getting an error on .replace.`The method replace(char, char) in the type String is not applicable for the 
 arguments (String)`.

Comment: @VrutiD You want to delete newarray[i] from the given line?

Comment: No, it reads from the array, but in the text file there are words that I wanted to delete from the sentences that is being printed. I got it working now.

Comment: I used the one above, I used your solution, but I have the error which  I mentioned.